# How to Get the Output/ Error while running Script as super user with subprocess.Popen Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have been trying to run a few shell commands through python. Some commands are run as super user. Everything goes fine until I run as sudo. In deed the problem is while running as superuser, stdout gives empty ouput whereas output is had when executed without sudo. In both cases,the command works fine, but I am not able to verify if the scrip gets successfully executed or not.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
cmd = 'gksudo rmdir /var/mydir' # or any othr command
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)enter code here
output = p.stdout.read()
print output
```

if the cmd is  `cmd=`'rmdir /var/mydir' 
It does give output. Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance`

Comment: It works for me with `sudo` (not `gksudo`)

Comment: Is the command requires a password? I mean does the current user belongs to sudo group. If not, how do you input that password>